# "Tracking" (debugging) what is happening in a Firebird 2.5 database

Tags: debugging, firebird, firebird2.5

I need some advice in how to handle the following:

Firebird 2.5 (I use Delphi XE2).

1. I have 2 structure identical database.
2. I have some triggers and SP on the table that I copy.
3. I copy 1-2-3 records from one table database to another.

trigger After Insert (execute one stored procedure that recompute some other records from the same table).

The database are identical but in one database the after insert work ok and in the other one no.
Also both trigger ARE working. (for testing purpose I raise an exception and is fire the exception).

So i want to find a way to track what is happening and to find the problem.
How to monitor/debug this situation. 
also how to track deadlock?

any advice?

Comment: Firebird trace will help you to find what is going wrong http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq95/

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the not working trigger is active.

Comment: Both trigger are working. (for testing purpose I raise an exception and is fire the exception).